# Trouble with cicle, one result, but it does not goes trought it

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a cicle for validation, but for some reason it does not go trought the cicle

Look at the comments, the while cicle it seems does nothing

If ther is any method to retrieve one result plase tell me how to do it

Here is my code, any help would be appreciated

```
private bool validar_ultimo_movimiento(Int64 cedula)
    {
        bool validar = false;


        DateTime tipo = Convert.ToDateTime("00:00:00");
        SqlConnection Wdcon_usuario = new SqlConnection(WDcon);
        SqlCommand usuario = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader usuarioDR = null;

        //Instancio la conexion SQL
        usuario.Connection = Wdcon_usuario;

        //Registro el Query SQL
        usuario.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM movimiento_docente WHERE (ID = @cedula) ORDER BY id_movimiento DESC";
        usuario.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedula", cedula);

        //Abro la conexion
        Wdcon_usuario.Open();

        //Ejecuto la consulta
        usuarioDR = usuario.ExecuteReader();

        //Empiezo el ciclo
        while (usuarioDR.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paso por aca 2"); // <- It does not execute
            if (usuarioDR["fechahora"].ToString() != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Paso por aca 3");
                tipo = (DateTime)usuarioDR["fechahora"];
                MessageBox.Show(tipo.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                validar = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Paso por aca 1");
            }
        }

        //Cierro la conexion
        Wdcon_usuario.Close();
        //Termino la sentencia SQL

        DateTime valoringresado = Convert.ToDateTime(dtHoraManual.Value);
        MessageBox.Show("Valor Ingresado = " + valoringresado.ToString() + " Valor BD = " + tipo.ToString());
        if (valoringresado > tipo)
        {
            validar = true;
        }
        else
        {
            validar = false;
        }
        return validar;
    }
```

Comment: I'm running into a bit of a language barrier here. If by cicle you mean the while loop, where does the validation come in? The while loop reads all the records that the query returns (one by one), is that not what is supposed to happen?

Comment: If you don't get into the while loop, that means the query returned 0 results, could that be it?

Comment: Yes is supposed to happen on the while loop, but it does not work, i have to retrieve 1 record only, but for some reason the while loop does not execute (usuarioDR.ExecuteReader() is the trigger to make the loop work)

Comment: I tested it on SQL Server, i have 4 or more records on that table, so it must retrieve 1 record with that query

Comment: Sure you have at least one record where the ID has that value?

Comment: Yes i have 5 values now with the ID i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for accessing the SQLDataReader object looks correct.

If I understand you properly, this `while` loop is not being run:

```
   //Empiezo el ciclo
    while (usuarioDR.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Paso por aca 2"); // <- It does not execute
        if (usuarioDR["fechahora"].ToString() != "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paso por aca 3");
            tipo = (DateTime)usuarioDR["fechahora"];
            MessageBox.Show(tipo.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            validar = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Paso por aca 1");
        }
    }
```

If this loop is not being run, it is because the `usuarioDR.Read()` function is returning a value of `false`. Here's some things to try and figure out what is going wrong:

Start debugging your code - a good first step would be to put a breakpoint at `while (usuarioDR.Read())` and see what information is contained in the `usuarioDR` object at that point in your function. Is there anything in the `usuarioDR` object? If there isn't, that means nothing is being pushed into `usarioDR` when you call `ExecuteReader()`.

Try approaching this from the other end - write out your `"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM movimiento_docente WHERE (ID = @cedula) ORDER BY id_movimiento DESC"` query in the Server Management Studio with a test value for `@cedula`. Does it generate the results you expect? If it does, then that means that your issue lies within your code and how it accesses the database.

In the end, I think it's going to come down to the standard debugging process: Set up breakpoints, step through your code, and check the data in your objects to see if it meets your expectations.

One place to start looking might be at your `usarioDR` object. You start by initializing it as `null`; is it still `null` after you run the line `usuarioDR = usuario.ExecuteReader();`? If it is, that might help you narrow your search.

Comment: On SQL Server Management Studio it gives me the result i expect, as you say the loop is not being run so i do not know what is happening here

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide some more solution tips. What you need to do is start some active debugging. You know what you want your code to do, which means you have an idea in your head about what should be happening on each line of your function. Step through your code line-by-line and try and verify that each line of the code (a) works the way you think it does, and (b) produces the result you expect. You're using C#, so I'm going to assume you're using Visual Studio. Set up some breakpoints at some of the lines in your function and use that to verify your code/data.

Comment: I alreadey tested on my code and sql server, it seems usuarioDR.Read() has this error "Empty "La enumeración no produjo ningún resultado" string " (It means "Enumeration yielded no results")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370165/datareader-returns-no-results-in-vs-yet-stored-procedure-returns-multiple-result might have some other things you can try. I think it's going to be difficult to come up with a specific answer, just because it seems to be dependent on the relationship between your application and your database. Again, this is probably going to require some active problem-solving and research on your part - if you get something you're not expecting, ask yourself 'why does it do this? How can I narrow it down?'

Comment: Done, i was passing the wrong parameter, took so long to realize it, i debugged line by line

Comment: Wonderful! Remember to upvote or accept answers if you have found them helpful.